# How to create Message List Screen?

Tags: android

I want to create the User interface in which contains Image Button, textbox and button at bottom. Title and label at the top of the screen and whenever user type and clicks the button I want to show entered text in rectangle with some color background like the floating bubble. When user enters another text then again i have to update the screen with entered text with another color in another rectangle with the timestamp at top of rectangle. So if first rectangle is inserted at left side then another should be shown at right side. My question is which layout should I use and how can I draw the rectangle and set background color? Rectangle should have arrow like in MSword Rectangle callout. Also I want to add scroll bar.

Thanks & Regards,
Devyani

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linear layout or relative layout within a scrollView (remember that the scrollview can handle only one child at a time, ie you can use only one layout within one scrollview). Insert a image of your choice (as you said call out box).

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply but text length is dynamic so how can i insert image based on text length?

Comment: i think it will be ok if you set the layout_height of the layout as "wrap parent" , the layout will accommodate the dynamic text, since you will be putting the EditText in the layout in which you have the image.(Linearlayout Background)

Answer (score 0):

to create rectangle's of different colors and alignments(left and right).
. create a class as such when ever u click the update button a new object of rectangle is created and updates the view.the color is picked using random functions in java. 
. set a boolean variable and for every update u would have an alternative left and right alignments when its true and false.
. for scrolling follow what rahul suggested. 
. looks similar to  a twitter app so find documentaion .

hope i am helpful and all da best